# (Android) Перезапуск метода при появлении интернета на устройстве

Tags: android

Добрый день!
В onCreate методе выполняется запрос данных с удаленного сервера (использую PostResponseAsyncTask). В случае, если на устройстве недоступно или отсутствует подключение к интернету, пользователю выводится соответствующее сообщение. Но хочется, чтобы приложение самостоятельно выполнило действия, описанные в onCreate, при появлении интернет соединения. Как это лучше реализовать?

```
public class cityActivity extends Activity {
private ArrayList<city> cityList;
private ListView lvCity;
FunDapter<city> adapter;

public void get_cityList() {
    lvCity = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(cityActivity.this, new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String s) {
            if (s == "") {
                Toast.makeText(cityActivity.this, "Проверьте подключение к интернету!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            cityList = new JsonConverter<city>().toArrayList(s, city.class);

            BindDictionary<city> dict = new BindDictionary<city>();
            dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCity, new StringExtractor<city>() {
                @Override
                public String getStringValue(city cityOption, int position) {
                    return cityOption.city_option;
                }
            });

            adapter = new FunDapter<>(cityActivity.this, cityList, R.layout.layout_city, dict);
            lvCity.setAdapter(adapter);
            initTextFilter(adapter);

        }
    });
    taskRead.setLoadingMessage("Загружаю список городов");
    taskRead.execute("example.com");

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            TextView tvCity = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
            String cityOption = tvCity.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(cityActivity.this, sferaActivity.class);

            // в ключ username пихаем текст из первого текстового поля
            intent.putExtra("cityOption",cityOption);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    };
    lvCity.setOnItemClickListener(itemListener);
}
...
```

Класс NetworkChangeReciever:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {
            // Do something

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы приложение выполнило какой-то код при появлении интернета?

Comment: Да. Если быть точным, чтобы приложение выполнило запрос данных, как это описано в методе onCreate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужен `BroadcastReceiver` который будет слушать состояние сети. и когда она есть можете выполнять нужные вам действия.

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {
            // Do something

            Log.d("Network Available ", "Flag No 1");
        }
    }
}
```

и интент фильтр

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
```

Ну и зарегестрировать его можно либо в `activity` либо `Manifest.xml` в теле тега `<application>`

```
<receiver android:name="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**UPD:**

Регистрируем в Активити:

```
public class cityActivity extends Activity {
private ArrayList<city> cityList;
private ListView lvCity;
FunDapter<city> adapter;

private String BROADCAST_ACTION = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        switch (action) {
            case BROADCAST_ACTION: 

final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {
            get_cityList();

            Log.d("Network Available ", "Flag No 1");
        }
                break;
            }
        }
    };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //...

   registerReceiver(receiver,IntentFilter); 
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver,IntentFilter); 
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

public void get_cityList() {
    lvCity = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(cityActivity.this, new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String s) {
            if (s == "") {
                Toast.makeText(cityActivity.this, "Проверьте подключение к интернету!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            cityList = new JsonConverter<city>().toArrayList(s, city.class);

            BindDictionary<city> dict = new BindDictionary<city>();
            dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCity, new StringExtractor<city>() {
                @Override
                public String getStringValue(city cityOption, int position) {
                    return cityOption.city_option;
                }
            });

            adapter = new FunDapter<>(cityActivity.this, cityList, R.layout.layout_city, dict);
            lvCity.setAdapter(adapter);
            initTextFilter(adapter);

        }
    });
    taskRead.setLoadingMessage("Загружаю список городов");
    taskRead.execute("http://remont.qwerq.ru/app/city_list.php");

//...
```

Comment: Подскажите, как вместо Do something вызвать метод из другого класса? Сложно для меня пока эти паблики, статики, прайваты... Сам запрос я убрал из onCreate метода класса cityActivity, создал отдельный метод get_cityList в том же классе cityActivity. Теперь, если я правильно все понимаю, нужно вызвать метод get_cityList по условию из класса NetworkChangeRiciever. Как это сделать?

Comment: обновите в вопросе ваши изменения в коде, покажите код активити с  методом get_cityList -  я туда допишу!

Comment: Обновил. Класс зарегистрирован через Manifest.xml

Comment: Обновил: регестрируем в Активити broadcastReceiver, прикрепляем к нему фильтр  и можем вызывать методы из активиты

Comment: @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }  Здесь ругается на intentFilter (Cannot resolve symbol intentFilter)

Comment: ага, поправил,  попробуйте!

Comment: Работает как надо! Огромное спасибо!

Comment: не за что, обратите внимание, что когда вы закрываете это активити или к примеру переходите на другое активити BroadcastReceiver перестает принимать сообщение, если вам нужно что бы ресивер срабатывал на уровне всего приложения - вам нужно его зарегестрировать в манифесте, если он нужен только в конкретном активити, то оставляйте как есть а в манифесте его не прописывайте.

Answer (score 0):

Немного подкорректированный ответ @kirill-stoianov
Работает как часы!

```
public class cityActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<city> cityList;
    private ListView lvCity;
    FunDapter<city> adapter;

    final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();

            switch (action) {
                case BROADCAST_ACTION: get_cityList();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_city);

        registerReceiver(receiver,intentFilter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

...
```